# JavaScript Coding for Finding Shipping Total

Tags: javascript

I am having a very hard time with this code. I have been working on it for days and cannot seem to figure it out. Please help!!

Here are the specific I need for the code:
Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling charge for purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box and includes a JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling charge. The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a shipping and handling charge of $5.00. After you determine the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box.

Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<head>
<title>Calculate Shipping</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function parseInt() {
var salesPrice = document.salesForm.Price.value;
var minCharge = salesPrice + 1.50;
var shipping = salesPrice * 10/100;
if (salesPrice <= 25)
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + minCharge);
 else 
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + salesPrice + shipping);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="salesForm">
<div >
<p>Enter Your Purchase Price</p>
<input type="text" name="Price" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" name="Calculate" value="Calculate Shipping"
onclick="parseInt ()" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works except for the math in the alert box. It will show an incorrect total...

Comment: Have you alert()ed all the values individually and they all look ok? Put some brackets around the addition in order to separate it from the string concatenation. Also, maybe specify floating point in your sales calculation (e.g. 10.0/100.0 rather than 10/100...though JS may be forgiving here)

Comment: You can't add `salesPrice` and `shipping` in the alert. It thinks it's a string.

Comment: Why did you call your function "parseInt"?

Comment: When I make an input of 74 (random example) my alert box will inform me that "Your sales total including shipping is $747.4". I think my mind is fried from this code. I am just not understanding it. I was told previously to try parseInt, but I am unsure where/how to use it properly. I'm so close but no matter what I try to change, I just can't seem to fix this issue...

Answer (score 2):

Input values are always returned as strings, not numbers; to address that:

```
var salesPrice = parseFloat(document.salesForm.Price.value),
    minCharge = salesPrice + 1.50,
    shipping = salesPrice * 10/100;
```

The problem is that `+` will either add numbers together, or concatenate strings:

```
var num1 = 1,
    num2 = 3,
    num3 = '2';
console.log(num1 + num2); // 4
console.log(num2 + num3); // '32'
```

References:

- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the wrong value because it is concatenating the strings instead of summing the values

You could either sum it up before alert them, like

```
var salesAndShipping = salesPrice + shipping
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + salesPrice + shipping);
```

Or you could simply parenthesized the expression, like:

```
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + (salesPrice + shipping) );
```

Oh and btw, I think you're overwriting a native function by calling yours `ParseInt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/J3yzu/4/)

```
function showAlert() {
var salesPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Price').value);    
var minCharge = salesPrice + 1.50;
var shipping = salesPrice * 10/100;
if (salesPrice <= 25)
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + minCharge);
    else {
window.alert('Your sales total including shipping is $' + parseFloat(salesPrice + shipping));
    }
}
```

Also parseInt is javascript method so you will see unexpected behaviors if you create method with same name. [Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)